# Apps unresponsive directly after starting them. Log says: "didn't gather any samples due to audio running"

Tags: macos, error

Recently, I'm seeing the following symptom regularly on my Mac.

I'll start an application such as safari or sktich and then the app bounces in the dock and is unresponsive. I have to force quit the application. This symptom is gone once I restart the mac.

All the log tells me is:

```
spindump[2733]: Safari [2730] didn't gather any samples due to audio running
```

**What could be the source of this error and how can I fix it**?

I have *no* audio running.

Comment: 1) Check the diagnostic files, if any, generated by `spindump` located in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`, hopefully you will find some hint to troubleshoot and fix the problem. 2) Make an appointment with a Genius at an Apple Store, if there's one in your area, to have them look at it.

Comment: @jaume I don't find any obvious spindumb log files, so I guess it's part of a different log file. But since there are so many, I have not found the exact file yet. I expected spotlight to search the contents of the log files, so that it would help me to find which logs contain the word "spindump" - but that's not working.

Comment: @gentmatt Did you ever find the solution?

I'm have the same issue with a customer.

Comment: @NSAddict I can't say for sure. However, there are two applications which have been causing trouble for me in the past because they interfere deeply with the operating system. 1) Sophos Antivirus. I was using it with an on-demand scanner enabled. I decided to completely remove this software. 2) HandsOff Firewall. I completely uninstalled and re-installed this application. Since then I have not experienced this symptom again. Obviously, I can't say for sure that these applications were related to the problem, but it was worth a shot.